# Using Sheets.Add, error using After parameter, "Expected Statement"

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am trying to add a worksheet to an existing workbook, placing the new worksheet after the prior. I can successfully add using `Sheets.Add`, but anytime I try to use the `After` parameter, I get an error, indicating "Expected Statement". It appears VBS does not like my `:=` operator.

Using the Excel macro editor, it seems as if this should work:

```
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
```

or this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Move After:=Sheets(4)
```

Either way, I run into the Expected Statement error. I have tried a variety of online examples, can't seem to find the right syntax. FWIW, this is a new install of Office 16, running on Windows 10.

Comment: Is there only one workbook open at the time?  (The macro  `Sub Macro1()` `Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet` `End Sub` works for me.  Try copying that into a module of a dummy workbook and see if it works for you.  If it doesn't, it might be something weird with your installation, but it just seems unlikely.)

Comment: Also try `Sheets.Add , ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but still no success. FWIW, this works:

Comment: This works:
Set xlApp=CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Sheets.Add.Name="Test1"
xlApp.Sheets.Add.Name="Test2"

This does not:
Set xlApp=CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Sheets.Add , ActiveSheet -- Add method of Sheets class failed.



The code:

xlApp.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

doesn't work because I get an "Expected Statement" message referencing character 24.

Comment: Ahh - I hadn't noticed the VBScript tag - I just saw the Excel-VBA tag.

Answer (score 2):

"Passing Arguments by Name" is not supported in VBScript syntax. You will need to do it with "Passing Arguments by Position" instead. e.g.

```
Sheets.Add Null, ActiveSheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Move , Sheets(4)
```

Ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838966.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834742.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below, it's better to set `wb` to the name of your Workbook, and also the name of your Sheet.

```
Sub AddSheet()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

'better to use this reference to wb object >> modify to your Workbook name
Set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")

'better to use this reference to sht object >> modify to your Sheet name
Set sht = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

wb.Sheets.Add After:=wb.Sheets(sht.Index)

End Sub
```

Comment: Shai, that code adds the new sheet to the active workbook, despite setting the reference to a specific workbook.  I think you need to use `wb.Sheets.Add After:=wb.Sheets(sht.Index)`

Comment: @YowE3K sorry, that's what happens when waking up so early :)

Comment: I got caught out on an answer yesterday - had just gotten through posting that all references should be qualified, then forgot to qualify some of the references in my own answer - oops.

Comment: I tried this approach, but I get an error when the code hits the := part of the statement -- I just can't seem to get past that. This might be a dumb question ;-), but the errors are reported in the Windows Script Host dialog box. Is that the default application for running VBS scripts, or do I need to configure something else? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are occurring for two reasons:

a) because you are trying to use objects that are part of the Excel application object that you created (`xlApp`) without telling VBScript that that's what they were, and

b) because VBScript does not support the concept of "named parameters" (at least, as far as I know it doesn't) so you have to use positional parameters.

So just saying `Sheets` is quite different from saying `xlApp.Sheets`, and the `After:=` syntax is not valid VBScript code.

The following code works for me:

```
Set xlApp=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb=xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlApp.Sheets.Add.Name="Test1"
xlApp.Sheets.Add.Name="Test2"
xlApp.Sheets.Add , xlApp.ActiveSheet
xlApp.Sheets.Add , xlApp.Sheets("Test1")
wb.SaveAs "TestWorkbook.xlsx"
wb.Close False
```

(My very first VBScript application - woohoo!!)

Comment: Thank you -- the one line I needed was xlApp.Sheets.Add , xlApp.ActiveSheet. I had tried a variety of permutations before, was just running out of options. FWIW, this code ran just fine until IT group installed Office 16 and Win 10, but all of a sudden it broke when creating additional sheets.  Finally, where did you find the the reference for the syntax you used? Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBeatty - I just based my syntax on your comment saying what worked.  I then typed what I thought the answer should be into a text editor, saved it as a .vbs file, then ran the .vbs file.